# How to generate binomial point estimate consistent with a binomial confidence interval?

Tags: binomial-distribution

Consider this sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

# slice of data
df = pd.DataFrame({'experiment': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
              'date': ['20230721', '20230722', '20230723', '20230724'],
              'success': [1, 1, 0, 1],
              'cum_success': [64, 65, 65, 66 ],
              'nobs': [121, 122, 123, 124]
              })

  experiment      date  success  cum_success  nobs
0          A  20230721        1           64   121
1          A  20230722        1           65   122
2          A  20230723        0           65   123
3          A  20230724        1           66   124
```

I can generate proportion confidence intervals like so:

```
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportion_confint

# 95% CI
df['low'] = proportion_confint(count=df['cum_success'], nobs=df['nobs'], alpha=0.05, method='jeffreys')[0]
df['high'] = proportion_confint(count=df['cum_success'], nobs=df['nobs'], alpha=0.05, method='jeffreys')[1]

  experiment      date  success  cum_success  nobs       low      high
0          A  20230721        1           64   121  0.440182  0.616304
1          A  20230722        1           65   122  0.444355  0.619684
2          A  20230723        0           65   123  0.440434  0.615155
3          A  20230724        1           66   124  0.444540  0.618489
```

But how can I generate a point estimate probability that is consistent with the CI?

````
# cant be right?
df['probSuccess'] = df.apply(lambda row: binom.pmf(row['cum_success'], \
                               row['nobs'], \
                                row['cum_success'] / row['nobs']), \
                                      axis=1)

  experiment      date  success  cum_success  nobs       low      high  \
0          A  20230721        1           64   121  0.440182  0.616304   
1          A  20230722        1           65   122  0.444355  0.619684   
2          A  20230723        0           65   123  0.440434  0.615155   
3          A  20230724        1           66   124  0.444540  0.618489   

   probSuccess  
0     0.072506  
1     0.072244  
2     0.071913  
3     0.071656  
```
````

Comment: idk how to read python code, but there is a bug, because 64/121 = 0.53, not 0.07

Comment: Are you saying that a binomial pmf unnecessary and the column could be computed just by: `cum_success` / `nobs`?

Comment: probably. is `cum_success/nobs` the proportion you are interested in?

Comment: Yep, that is my proportion of interest.

Comment: then yes, just compute it that formula :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the probability by `cum_success/nobs`